# pylint - where is the pylintrc documentation?

Tags: pylint

[Running Pylint](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/stable/user_guide/usage/run.html)

> Specifying all the options suitable for your setup and coding standards can be tedious, so it is possible to **use a configuration file to specify the default values**. You can specify a configuration file on the command line using the --rcfile option. Otherwise, Pylint searches for a configuration file in the following order and uses the first one it finds:

Place the max-line-length but it complains there is no section. Where is the documentation of how to format the pylintrc file?

**~/.pylintrc**

```
max-line-length=120
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use the latest version of pylint where no sections are required. The configuration documentation is [here](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/configuration/index.html)

You can [generate a configuration file automatically](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=generate%20configuration#how-do-i-find-the-name-corresponding-to-a-specific-command-line-option):

```
pylint --generate-toml-config
```

In practice, it is often better to create a minimal configuration file which only contains configuration overrides. For all other options, Pylint will use its default values.

Comment: Also the https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/stable/user_guide/usage/run.html#command-line-options which explains where pylint looks for either `pylintrc` (from `--generate-rcfile`) or `pyproject.toml` (from `--generate-toml-config`)